# Cannot play .mkv files after installing Codecs

Tags: vlc, totem, mkv

After installing codecs to watch files in x265, the Totem player now doesn't play .mkv files any more.

It says it is invalid and shows this:

```
--transient-for=69206027 gstreamer|1.0|totem|Matroska demuxer|decoder-video/x-matroska
```

I can still watch them with VLC, but still, the image sometimes gets quiet pixelated.

Can someone please help me?